# How to render a multiple value field of type generic file

Tags: entities

If I use the textformatter module (included textformatter_contrib) I can display a repeatable field with links as a list.

By selecting 'list' as format for the full view of the field of the content type.
I can't select 'list' for the file field.
The default format for my file field is 'generic file'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That module provides formatters for the following field types:

- entityreference
- node_reference
- user_reference
- link
- field_collection

(gathered from [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/textformatter.git/blob/9e709800b2cb12404062586215229f946d169ca5:/textformatter_contrib/textformatter_contrib.module)).

There's no support for file fields so you'll need to either implement the functionality yourself, or file a feature request to the [Textformatter issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/textformatter?categories=All).